# How to rename values based on the condition in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
Product_Id  State  County  Statecode  Sales  Qty
182938      CA     KSO     234        2283   23
182237      AL     GSK     384        3448   45
182367      HK     RYU     347        3944   29
182999      AH     NSI     391        2746   39
182938      CA     KSO     173        2738   99
182367      HK     RYU     198        3748   12
```

I need to change some values in my dataframe because it doesn't make sense. If you see for STATE- (CA & KSO) Where all dimension are same like (Product_Id  State  County) but state code is different. I want make all statecode unique for each combination, I want it to be picked the state code for each combination and replace the state code accordingly.

output_df:

```
Product_Id  State  County  Statecode  Sales  Qty
182938      CA     KSO     234        2283   23
182237      AL     GSK     384        3448   45
182367      HK     RYU     347        3944   29
182999      AH     NSI     391        2746   39
182938      CA     KSO     234        2738   99  -- state code picked from the first occurrence
182367      HK     RYU     347        3748   12  -- state code picked from the first occurrence
```

What I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

# Find duplicate rows
df_duplicates= df.duplicated(subset=['Product_Id','State','County'])
df[df_duplicates] --> it will the duplicate rows

Product_Id  State  County  Statecode  Sales  Qty
182938      CA     KSO     234        2283   23
182938      CA     KSO     173        2738   99
182367      HK     RYU     347        3944   29
182367      HK     RYU     198        3748   12
```

Comment: Use `df['Statecode'] = df.groupby(['Product_Id','State','County'])['Statecode'].transform('first')`